# LLDB: How to do a step by step execution of 'po [myObject method]' name?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, breakpoints, lldb

I have my app execution stopped in an unrelated breakpoint.

I want to do a step by step execution of a completely different `method`.

Doing `po [myObject method]` on the console prints the correct result, but I want to do step-by-step execution to see how this `method` result is calculated. Setting an enabled breakpoint inside `method` doesn't help, as `po [myObject method]` doesn't seem to trigger it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of research I found out, you can evaluate the expression while having it stop at breakpoints like this:

```
 expr -o -i 0 -- [myObject method]
```

(`po` is just an alias for `expr -o`. The `-i 0` flag is what makes it stop at breakpoints.)